# Move all elements with class inside div

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, class, nodes

I'm brand new to js, and tried to move every elements with certain class inside a certain div.
I made some research and saw a solution that works with id, but when I tried to change it to classNames it didn't work anymore.
Is there anything more to write ?

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="bottom">bottom 1</div>
<div class="bottom">bottom 2</div>
<div id="top">top</div>
```

and my script so far

```
document.getElementById('top').appendChild(document.getElementsByClassName('bottom'))
console.log(document.getElementById('top').innerHTML)
```

I understood that appendChild didn't work because document.getElementsByClassName('bottom') is an array string instead of a node, but I have absolutely no idea what a node is, neither how to change my code for it to work.

I would really appreciate any help at all !
Thanks.

Comment: [`.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) only can handle single elements. [`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a list of elements. Find a way to access the elements in that list and use those with `.appendChild()` -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const t = document.getElementById('top');
[...document.getElementsByClassName('bottom')].map(el => t.appendChild(el));
```

```html
<div class="bottom">bottom 1</div>
<div class="bottom">bottom 2</div>
<div id="top">top</div>
```

Comment: If you don't use the return value of `.map()` then `.map()` is the wrong tool.

Comment: @FlorentMerviel Why did you choose this one? Ezios answer was already 10 minutes old at the time of this answer, does the exact same (just with `Array.from()` instead of `...`) and actually uses the right tools

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```js
const top = document.getElementById('top');
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('bottom')).forEach(bottom => top.appendChild(bottom))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const top = document.getElementById('top');
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass");

[].forEach.call(elements, function(el) {
    el.appendChild(bottom);
});
```

u can also use this syntax but its not compatible with older browsers like IE:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.myclass').forEach(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = '';
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('bottom');
for (let i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    html += elems[i].outerHTML;
}
document.getElementById('top').innerHTML = html;
```